# VB.NET null coalescing operator?

Tags: vb.net, null-coalescing-operator

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Coalesce operator and Conditional operator in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629036/coalesce-operator-and-conditional-operator-in-vb-net)
>   [Is there a VB.NET equivalent for C#'s ?? operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator)

Is there a built-in VB.NET equivalent to the C# null coalescing operator?

Comment: possibel dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629036/coalesce-operator-and-conditional-operator-in-vb-net

Comment: Since VS 2015, its now possible to use ?. in vb.Net.

`Dim x = Obj?.Child?.AnotherChild?.Something?.AString`
x is a string that will be Nothing if any object is nothing, or set if all objects are not nothing.

Comment: @Edamreed you shoud make that an answer on at least one of the duplicates or this question.

Comment: @Edamreed `?.` is the null-conditional operator (aka safe navigation operator), not the `??` null-coalescing operator that the question asks about.

Answer (score 126):

Yes, there is, a long as you're using VB 9 or later (included with Visual Studio 2008).

You can use the version of the [`If` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) overloaded to accept only two arguments:

```
Dim myVar? As Integer = Nothing
Console.WriteLine(If(myVar, 7))
```

More information can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/03/11/if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim.aspx) in a blog post by the VB.NET team.

(Yes, this is an **operator**, even though it looks like a function. It will compile down to the same IL as the "proper" null-coalescing operator in C#.)

**Example**

```
Dim b As Boolean?
Console.WriteLine("{0}.", If(b, "this is expected when b is nothing"))
'output: this is expected when b is nothing.

b = False
Console.WriteLine("{0}.", If(b, "this is unexpected when b is false"))
'output: False.

b = True
Console.WriteLine("{0}.", If(b, "this is unexpected when b is true"))
'output: True.
```

Comment: It should be noted that as opposed to the C# operator, the VB.NET implementation does not allow for throw expressions. It only accepts value expressions.

Comment: Linked blog article on the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150716145313/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/03/11/if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim.aspx

Answer (score 11):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator) it would seem the answer is [If()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)

Comment: If you find a duplicate question, please flag the question as a duplicate rather than posting an answer that links to the duplicate question. That helps to keep down clutter on the site. Only post an answer if you think you can *add value* to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't realise; will certainly bear it in mind for the future though.

Answer (score -3):

No. Use `GetValueOrDefault`; that's why it's there!

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault(ByVal default As T)` forces evaluation of the default parameter even if it is  not required, the null-coalescing operator will only evaluate default if `HasValue` is false.

Answer (score -3):

I don't believe that there is a built in VB.Net equivalent, but here's an answer: [null coalesce operator in VB.Net(8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594446/null-coalesce-operator-in-vb-net8)

Comment: If you find a duplicate question, please flag the question as a duplicate rather than posting an answer that links to the duplicate question. That helps to keep down clutter on the site. Only post an answer if you think you can *add value* to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Cody Gray -- thanks, will do next time.