# vb.net: How is it ? or ?? conditional in c# for vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

In C# we have this conditional assignment:

```
var test = 1;
var something = (test == 1)? "P":"C";
```

Or

```
var test = null;
var something = test ?? "";
```

Is it possible to do it in vb.net?

I am using to program in c# but in this project I am programming in vb.net, and I don't remember if it is possible to do it.

Comment: One duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792729/vb-net-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: The other question is answered by using the version of `if` that takes only two parameters

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a VB.NET equivalent for C#'s ?? operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator)

Comment: when I was finding the question I didnt find them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [`If`-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) which can be used with one or two parameters. The null-coalescing operator(`??`) in C# is the `If` with one parameter and the conditional operator(`?`) is the one with two parameters.

"Conditional-Operator"

```
Dim test As Int32 = 1
Dim something As String = If(test = 1, "P", "C")
```

"Null-Coalescing-Operator"

```
Dim test As String = Nothing
Dim something As String = If(test, "") ' "" is the replacement value for null '
```

Note that the `If`-operator is not the same as the old [`IIf`-function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) : [Performance difference between IIf() and If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/iif-vs-if)