# Linq to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How to get rid of "If then else" ?

```
  If qShoppingCartByCartID.Invoke(_context).Count > 0 Then
            Return qShoppingCartByCartID.Invoke(_context).Select(Function(x) x.Products.UnitCost - x.Products.SalePrice).Sum
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is empty then Sum() will return `null` - so you could just return the sum:

```
  Return qShoppingCartByCartID.Invoke(_context).Select(Function(x) x.Products.UnitCost - x.Products.SalePrice).Sum()
```

In C# you could also use `??` to turn that into a zero instead of null if you wanted to

```
  return qShoppingCartByCartID....Sum() ?? 0;
```

I'm not a VB user, but it looks like you can do this same null coallescing in VB using `If` - see [Is there a VB.NET equivalent for C#'s '??' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator)

Comment: The select part of the query triggers the error, because the list is empty. I don't think that your query in c# gonna work too. because the list is empty so there is no values for the select part (x.Products.UnitCost -x.Products.SalePrice).

Comment: I'm confused - which list is empty? x.Products? What happens if you put the projection into the Sum - like `.Sum(Function(x) x.Products.UnitCost - x.Products.SalePrice)`?