# VB.NET similar function to "ISNULL" available in SQL?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have this in my VB.NET code:

```
Dim myValue as String
myValue = ""
Dim myDblValue as Double
myDblValue CDbl(Val(myValue))
```

If `myValue` string is `null` [like in this example], I'd like to set the value to a predefined value for example `999`. I know in SQL I can use `ISNULL` for that. Is there any equivalent in VB.NET? If not, how can it be done with available functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a VB.NET equivalent for C#'s ?? operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator)

Comment: dont use `Val` there are much better converters in NET

Comment: myValue is not null in your example.  It is an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the String Methods `IsNullOrEmpty` or `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to create you own function something like this.

```
Public Function TestNull(value As String, defaultValue As String) as String
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
        Return defaultValue
    Else
        Return value
    End If
End Function
```

Usuage:

```
myDblValue = CDbl(Val(TestNull(myValue, "999")))
```

Or since you are converting to a double you can just use the Double.TryParse Method it will fail if it can't be converted for any reason

```
Public Function TestValidDecimal(value As String, defaultValue As Double) As Double
    Dim temp As Double
    If Double.TryParse(value, temp) Then
        Return temp
    Else
        Return defaultValue
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question,  IF operator is the nearest to ISNULL when used with the String.IsNull method.

Like this

```
    Dim myValue As String
    myValue = ""
    Dim myDblValue As Double

    Dim myDefaultValue As Double = 10.1 ' what ever you need

    myDblValue = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myValue), myDefaultValue, CDbl(myValue))
```

If you need to worry about invalid text in myValue then you can use the Double.TryParse method like this.

```
    Dim myValue As String
    myValue = ""
    Dim myDblValue As Double

    Dim myDefaultValue As Double = 10.1 ' what ever you need

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(myValue) OrElse Not Double.TryParse(myValue, myDblValue) Then
        myDblValue = myDefaultValue
    End If
```

Comment: Using IIF in this way will generate an exception if `myValue` is Nothing because both all of the expressions in the IIF fuction will be evaluated (including the `CDbl`.  IIF does not short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

```
If YourVariable.IsNullOrEmpty Then
     myValue = DoWhateverYouWant
Else
     DoOtherStuff
End If
```

Comment: Just `If(myValue.IsNullOrEmpty, 999, ???)`. IIf has been depricated because it evaluates both the true and false expressions.

Comment: @JonathanAllen thanks for clearing that up. Is there a link you can provide? I looked before I posted but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

myDblValue = If(myValue = Nothing, 999, CDbl(Val(myValue)))

OR

myDblValue = If(myValue = "", 999, CDbl(Val(myValue)))

SEE:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=vs.90).aspx